# What was the last episode/movie Majel Barrett recorded?

Tags: star-trek, voice-acting

Majel Barrett's voice was used for the computer voice in every Star Trek series (and most of the movies) after TOS. [She even did a bunch of phonetic recordings that could be used in future projects.](http://globalnews.ca/news/2930723/majel-barrett-may-voice-star-trek-discovery-ship-computer/)

What was the last Star Trek episode or movie that Majel Barrett personally recorded?

Comment: Make it yourself -Majel https://youtu.be/dFlFe-Tix0k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Her last Star Trek related cinematic work was in the 2009 reboot ***Star Trek***. The lens flare-iffic clip below has her mocking young Chekov:

But her last Star Trek related work was the 2010 MMORPG ***Star Trek Online***. I'm not certain how much she recorded for it, how much is clips, and how much is her impersonator, Lani Minella.

She also did some recording for ***Hamlet A.D.D.***, an animated film that wasn't released until 2014.

[Of course, ever the forward thinkers, Majel had recorded herself phonetically, so that future technology can be used to ensure her voice can continue to be used.](http://www.bleedingcool.com/2016/09/06/majel-barrett-may-yet-voice-star-trek-discovery-computer/) As the [official Roddenberry twitter says](https://twitter.com/roddenberry/status/772493204121944066?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw):

```
 RODDENBERRY  ✔@roddenberry
 Majel's voice is recorded phonetically,
 & we're working to get her voice for things such as Siri,
 maybe voice of the computer on #STDiscovery
 1:55 PM - 4 Sep 2016
```

So, its possible that we will see her voice future episodes, through the magic of science fact.

Answer (score 2):

[According to her IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000854/), 2010? After her death, though and Star Trek 2009, which she may have recorded in studio though it was released after her death.

Comment: Can you actually write the title rather than this bare link to IMDb?

Comment: I would if I knew how!

Comment: @WillowRex https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7dqA.png